# Convert hexadecimal to human readable string with Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, hex

I am using the component TComPort to read/write the RFID Reader device throught a COM Port with Delphi Berlin 10.1

This is how I write the command:

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComPort1.WriteStr(#$5A#$FE#$01#$00#$0D#$0A);
end;
```

This is how I read the response from the device:

```
procedure TForm1.ComDataPacket1Packet(Sender: TObject; const Str: string);
var
  str2:String;
  I:Integer;
begin
  for I:=1 to length(str) do
    begin
      str2 := str2+IntToHex(Byte(str[I]),2)+' ';
    end;
  memo1.lines.add(str2);
end;
```

The the response is **D5 D5 03 00 82 D2 04 58 01 0D 0A**

Which I think means **1234** or at least that is what the analyzer says
[image]

But, how can I convert that Hexadecimal to a human readable string like **1234**?

Comment: Can you please explain how are we going to end up with 1234 with that hex value? Calc.exe reports that 1234 decimal is $4D2.

Comment: 1234 is $04D2 in hex. If the 6th pair is the lsb and the 7th pair is the msb, then you can figure out the rest.

Comment: ISTM that the `0D 0A` at the end could be a CR+LF, but I have no idea what the other bytes could mean.

Comment: Surely you have the protocol description. `OD 0A` is CR LF, which normally terminates a message.

Comment: I added a picture from the analyzer output

Comment: My first comment answers your question. What is it you don't understand?

Comment: What is the device? Do you have the manufacturer and model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is:  D5 D5 03 00 82 D2 04 58 01 0D 0A

From your question is seems clear that `str[6]` is the lsb of the pertinent part of the answer and `str[7]` holds the msb.

> How did I come to that conclusion?

1234 is `$04D2` hex. The most significant (msb) part is `$04` and the least significant (lsb) part is `$D2`.

A crude conversion to a string could be:

```
s := IntToStr(Byte(str[6]) + Word(str[7])*256); // Outputs 1234
```

First, the lsb is added to the msb multiplied with 256 to form a value, which then is converted to a resulting string.

---

All of this should be much easier if you studied the protocol description of your device. Surely the vendor supplies this information.

Comment: I will try it now, but the vendor does not supply any information about the device, even I had to discover the baud rate with a debugger.

Comment: @MartinOcandoCorleone then how do you expect to interact with this device if you dont know how it communicates? You need that information. The vendor must have intended the device to communicate with something, otherwise it wouldnt have a COM port connection. So someone somewhere has to have documented how the device's communication protocol works.

Comment: Remy, the support does not answer my emails, I had to find out how it works by my self, not documentation over there, until now I have enough information of how it works, and thanks to LU now I can decode it very well